# Biblatex, multiple bibliographies and reusing articles locally

Tags: biblatex

I stumbled upon a strange effect in Biblatex, and maybe someone can help me solve it. I have the following goal:

- a global publication list of important things (by category)
- a global list for the rest
- a local list of things (by category?)

Where in the local scope, e.g. a section, the local references get the local (prefixed) number and if I refer to global things (i.e. not from the local category) the global label is used. The following example does not have just-local references, but they should not be a problem (since local 1 can be excluded from the globals for example).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
  @article{a,
    author={A},
    title={A1},
    journal={A2},
    year={2019},
  }
  @article{b,
    author={B},
    title={B1},
    journal={B2},
    year={2019},
  }
  @article{c,
    author={C},
    title={C1},
    journal={C2},
    year={2019},
  }
  @article{d,
    author={D},
    title={D1},
    journal={D2},
    year={2019},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{local1}

\begin{document}
  I am citing in general a\cite{a} (should be I-1),\\
  as well as (b,c,d)\cite{b,c,d} (should be I-2,1,2).
  \addtocategory{important}{a}
  \addtocategory{important}{b}
  
  \paragraph{Important Publications,}
  \begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=I-]
    \printbibliography[heading=none,category=important]
  \end{refcontext}

  \paragraph{Other Publications,}
    \printbibliography[heading=none,notcategory=important, resetnumbers]
  
  \section{My own next local Project}
  Here I would like to also cite two types:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item things that get reassigned locally,\\
      for example (a,c)\cite{a,c} (should be L-1,L-2)
    \item things that stay from the global scope,\\
    as (b,d)\cite{b,d} (should be I-2,2)
  \end{itemize}

  \addtocategory{local1}{a}
  \addtocategory{local1}{c}
  \paragraph{Locally important Publications}
  \begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=L-]
    \printbibliography[heading=none,category=local1]
  \end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

where I already denoted which references I expect. Note especially references a. Globally it should be `I-1` since it is in the important category, locally it should get `L-1` as printed in the following screenshot:

[image: result of BibLatex]

But: It's actually the wrong way around: globally it get's the local number, locally the global one. At least one of those mixups really confuses me. Also for a normal article like `c` the reference seems to be used the wrong way around.

- Why is that happening?
- How can I get the “right” (i.e. the ones I wrote in brackets) reference labels?
- **Adendum:** Can I only really do that locally, i.e. such that `L-1` is again `I-1` (and `L-2` again `1`) after the local section?

Answer (score 2):

The documented behaviour would be that all citations take their refcontext from the last bibliography they appear in.

It is a matter of interpretation whether you read that 'last' in an absolute absolute or relative sense.

Naively, I would have read it absolute and so would have expected that `a` and `c` should appear as "L-1" and "L-2" in *all* citations.

At the moment, however, this 'last' is relative. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/904. That means that citations take their refcontext from the previous bibliography they appeared in and if there is no such bibliography then from the (absolute) bibliography they appear in.

This explains why we get the output we are seeing. When `a` and `c` are cited at the beginning of the document, they get the refcontext of the absolute last bibliography that contains them (`labelprefix=L-`), but when they get cited the second time they appear after the `labelprefix=I-` bibliography, so appear in that refcontext.

The following MWE shows how you can get the desired output.

First we define a local version of `\assignrefcontextcats` that allows us to *locally* assign the refcontext based on categories (the same could be done for keywords or a list of keys, but you are using only categories). We'll use that command to locally switch to the `labelprefix=L-` context (`\assignrefcontextcatslocal[labelprefix=L-]{local1}`).

Then we only need to get the contexts for the rest of the document right. We need to stop the 'last bibliography' wins rule for `local1` with

```
\assignrefcontextcats[]{local1}
```

but then we also need to make sure that the `important` entry gets the correct context with

```
\assignrefcontextcats[labelprefix=I-]{important}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}


\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{local1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\assignrefcontextcatslocal}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\blx@assignrefcontextcatslocal[*]}
    {\blx@assignrefcontextcatslocal[]}}

\def\blx@assignrefcontextcatslocal[#1][#2]#3{%
  \edef\blx@tempa{\blx@sorting}%
  \def\blx@tempb{global}%
  \let\blx@tempc\@empty%
  \def\blx@tempd{global}%
  \def\blx@tempe{global}%
  \setkeys{blx@assignrefcontext}{#2}%
  \def\do##1{%
    \listeadd\blx@assignedrefcontextcatlist{##1}%
    \csedef{blx@assignedrefcontextcats#1@\the\c@refsection @##1}%
      {\blx@tempa/\blx@tempb/\blx@tempc/\blx@tempd/\blx@tempe}}%
  \docsvlist{#3}}
\makeatother

\assignrefcontextcats[]{local1}
\assignrefcontextcats[labelprefix=I-]{important}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
  author  = {A},
  title   = {A1},
  journal = {A2},
  year    = {2019},
}
@article{b,
  author  = {B},
  title   = {B1},
  journal = {B2},
  year    = {2019},
}
@article{c,
  author  = {C},
  title   = {C1},
  journal = {C2},
  year    = {2019},
}
@article{d,
  author  = {D},
  title   = {D1},
  journal = {D2},
  year    = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  I am citing in general a\cite{a} (should be I-1),
  as well as (b,c,d)\cite{b,c,d} (should be I-2,1,2).
  \addtocategory{important}{a}
  \addtocategory{important}{b}

  \paragraph{Important Publications,}
  \begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=I-]
    \printbibliography[heading=none,category=important]
  \end{refcontext}

  \paragraph{Other Publications,}
    \printbibliography[heading=none,notcategory=important, resetnumbers]

\begingroup
  \section{My own next local Project}
  \addtocategory{local1}{a}
  \addtocategory{local1}{c}
  \assignrefcontextcatslocal[labelprefix=L-]{local1}

  Here I would like to also cite two types:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item things that get reassigned locally,
      for example (a,c)\cite{a,c} (should be L-1,L-2)
    \item things that stay from the global scope,
    as (b,d)\cite{b,d} (should be I-2,2)
  \end{itemize}


  \paragraph{Locally important Publications}
  \begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=L-]
    \printbibliography[heading=none,category=local1]
  \end{refcontext}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: I am citing in general a[I-1] (should be I-1), as well as (b,c,d)[I-2, 1, 2] (should be I-2,1,2).//things that get reassigned locally, for example (a,c)[L-1, L-2] (should be L-1,L-2)//things that stay from the global scope, as (b,d)[I-2, 2] (should be I-2,2)]

---

It might have made sense to just separate the 'My next local project' section with `refsection`, but then you couldn't have cited entries that don't belong to `local1` as normal. You would needed a separate bibliography for those as well.